# How to add the connection from outlet inspector in Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am a newbie to Xcode and programming. I need to establish connections to labels from the connection inspector. I defined the labels but the inspect outlet is not showing them.
Below is the code:

*Note: using Xcode 12 the newest version.*

```
import UIKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel:UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel:UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel:UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var inputField:UITextField?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a story board or nib?  The view's class is defined as `GameViewController` in the inspector?  As a general rule, you can force unwrap (`!`) the outlets as the system guarantees there availability by the time `viewDidLoad` is called

Comment: i have a storyboard

Comment: I've cued this video up to the spot that shows you how to do it. Just control drag. https://youtu.be/jyUtCmzo2XM?t=53

Comment: @SkyZeen did you actually set your the class of your storyboard viewcontroller to `GameViewController` from identity inspector?

Comment: in the identity inspector, it shows as the GameViewController.swift

Answer (score 4):

First, in the storyboard, select the view controller and make sure the controllers "class" is defined as `GameViewController`

[image: View controller class]

Once this is done/confirmed, you should be able to flip over to outlet inspector and see the available outlets

[image: Outlets]

You should then be able to drag a link from your source code onto the component you want to connect with.

1. Select the source code view
2. Click and hold on the outlet marker and
3. Drag to the component you want to connect to

[image: Link them]

You can do in the other direction (from the storyboard to the source code), but you need to hold the [Command] key while you do it